# Process huge numpy array in chunks using dask

Tags: numpy, dask

I have a Numpy array array shape (9482138, 78045191) and data type int64 on which I want to perform a `.sum(axis=0)`. I am unable to allocate this array in memory, so I tried to do this:

```
# My array is named `arr`

list_of_sums = []

import dask.array as da
chunked = da.from_array(arr, chunks=100000)
for chunk in chunks:
    sums = chunk.sum(axis=0)
    list_of_sums.append(sums)
```

This method does not work, as it throws the same ”unable to allocate” memory error, as when working directly with the numpy array unchunked.

Comment: It looks like you're already allocating the memory for the array in ```arr``` - if you could show how you're loading the variable that would be more useful. If you're reading from file, have a look at ```from_delayed``` which will allow you to lazily load in the data.

Comment: @Ian The `arr` is a scipy csr sparse matrix upon which I have done `.toarray()`

Comment: It feels like a combination of the sparse library https://github.com/mrocklin/sparse and this article should bring you to a solution; https://docs.dask.org/en/latest/array-sparse.html. I don't think you can easily get around the ```toarray()``` step without converting to another format first.